# in which segment constant data is stored?

Tags: c, linux

I was trying to understand in which segment constant data is stored.

for example

```
const int x = 100
```

1) Where x is stored? In code segment or data segment?

2) is there any 'read only' data segment exists in initialized data segment?

Comment: We know because you haven't told us the storage class of x.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The data will be stored in any segment, or multiple segments, or no segment at all, depending on the specifics of the compiler, compiler flags, linker, linker flags, and surrounding code.

On Linux/ELF, if it is stored somewhere, it will *usually* get stored in the `.rodata` section which is inside a segment with `r-x` permissions.  ELF segments do not have names, as far as I know.

However, in many cases, constants like these will get inlined.

Comment: I think it also depends on where this line of code is placed, global or local. If x is a global const, the compiler may not inline it for it's an exported variable. But if x is a local const, it is most likely that it is inlined.

Comment: If x is defined with extern storage class, it must be stored regardless of whether *uses* of it are inlined. "if x is a local const" -- then it is placed on the stack if storage for it is required (e.g., if its address is taken).

Comment: @JimBalter: Incorrect.  The C compiler must only guarantee that for global `const int x;` any `&x` equals `&x`.  If the address of `x` is never taken, then the compiler is not required to store the value of `x` in any location, *even if `x` has `extern` storage class*.

Comment: I suppose that's true, although a citation of the standard would be useful. gcc does allocate space for it, though.

Comment: @JimBalter: It depends on the settings.  Try `-fwhole-program` with higher optimization settings, or `-Wl,--gc-sections`.

Comment: @JimBalter: I claimed that the standard does not require `x` to be emitted, and it's a bit hard to cite something that I claim isn't even the standard at all.  The C standard generally only specifies the behavior of programs, e.g., `&x` has a distinct value from pointers to other objects, but the same value in all translation units.  From this you can infer that memory must be allocated which contains the value of `x`.  But the standard permits an amazing variety of transformations and optimizations, and in the absence of `&x` in your code, even more is permissible.

Comment: yeah, well, I found it for you ... footnote 132 in 6.7.3: "132) The implementation may place a
const
object that is not
volatile
in a read-only region of
storage. Moreover, the implementation need not allocate storage for such an object if its address is
never used." Of course footnotes aren't normative, but it does help confirm that your claim is valid.

Answer (score 3):

Probably not in any segment since such constants are resolved at compile time, and their values used directly when needed.

In general there is the **rodata** section, which stands indeed for read-only data section, which is a special section inside *usually* data segment meant to be used exactly for this purpose

Comment: `rodata` is a section, not a segment.

Comment: "since such constants are resolved at compile time" -- This is a bizarre and misleading use of the word "resolve". I suggest that you read what the C standard says about const, because it's nothing like how you apparently imagine it. Presumably x is neither local nor static ... thus, memory must be allocated for it.

Comment: @JimBalter: memory will be allocated for the value, not to hold a reference to it. Unless you are using the address of `x` nothing prevents the compiler from inlining them and use the value directly in the instructions without actually load it from the data section.

Comment: " memory will be allocated for the value" -- that's what I said. "not to hold a reference to it" -- eh? No one said anything about references to x. "nothing prevents the compiler from inlining them" -- no one said otherwise. Look, YOU said "Probably not in any segment since such constants are resolved at compile time" -- that's wrong; that the compiler can inline the value of x where it has used has nothing to do with whether it appears in a segment -- it does, if it's got extern storage scope.